# Angular 14 flex layout issue

Tags: angular, angular14

while running serve, i am facing this issue with node modules for flex layout.
Class 'MockMediaQueryList' incorrectly implements interface 'MediaQueryList'.

Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'MockMediaQueryList' but required in type 'MediaQueryList'.

59 export declare class MockMediaQueryList implements MediaQueryList {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5144:5
5144     prototype: EventTarget;

Can anyone suggest solution for this.
i am using angular 14 and flex-layout version as 14.0.0-beta

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I go to the tsconfig.json and add "skipLibCheck": true to fix this issue